# How can I get all the water to go down the drain in this sink?

Tags: plumbing, sink

I have this sink, which is sort of inclined to the back, causing water to build up on the back part. Here's a picture

[image]

The sink can't be replaced easily as it is cast along with the kitchen counter. Is there any way I can get all the water to go into the drain?

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell from that picture, but you may be able to shim the cabinets to make the sink and countertop more level.

If not, you can (if the sink bottom is not too thin) grind it (diamond will take on anything, but silicon carbide is a lot cheaper, so try that first) to fix the slope - but it looks like you'll also have to remove and reseat the drain - the strainer appears to sit up from the sink bottom, where it should sit down into it for proper drainage.

Comment: Agreed about using shims - it looks like it settled towards the back as you can see where the caulk used to be versus where it is now

Answer (score 0):

Use a squeegee - a floor version might be a good bet here.

[image]

I must say thats a pretty fundamental design flaw - a properly designed stone sink would slope down towards the hole, or at least be laid flat so as to not have water pool on one side.